# Can I make an ajax request in Javascript to update my shopping cart items' quantities in opencart 3.0.3.8?

Tags: javascript, ajax, opencart, e-commerce, opencart-3

I'm trying to add plus and minus buttons to the cart to increase and decrease the quantity of a cart. Adding to the cart is simple with `cart.add()` but decreasing the quantity is more complicated. The `cart.update()` function does not work according to  [this github issue.](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/6673) Is it possible to update the cart using ajax? If so, how is that accomplished?

Here is the function in question that does not work.

```
var cart = {
    'update': function(key, quantity) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },
            success: function(json) {
                // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
                }, 100);

                if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                    location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                } else {
                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: Is that issue relevant still considering the issue was closed four years ago? Before you rewrite anything, have you looked at implementing the proposed solution: adding a new controller function?

Comment: @Daniel I believe that the issue is still relevant because the function does not work properly, although the code has been altered a little. I do not know PHP so I was seeking a solution in Javascript if possible.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to achieve what you want to without working with PHP given [the issue](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/6673) you've mentioned. When you say '...the function does not work..' which of the solution in the issue feedback did you try?